# Showing a bootbox.js dialog to make a selection during dropzone.js form action while sending to node.js server

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, dropzone.js, bootbox

I have a node.js/express site which has an upload dropbox which use dropzone.js to do drag and drop uploads. My dropzone inside my jade template looks like this currently:

```
div(id="dropzone")
form(method="POST" action="/upload" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone")
    div(class="dz-message")
        span Drop your zipped AgentCubes project here to upload it
```

This currently works fine, but in the case where the user uploads the same file again I would like to provide the option to overwrite the old file or generate a new name for the duplicate upload. This would not work with my current scheme which simply sends the file /upload which is an express endpoint I have created which currently handles the upload.

It is also complicated by the fact that I would need to post to the server to decide if the file is a duplciate upload, then show the bootbox.js dialog in the client and then finally send the upload data to the server. I have looked through the dropzone.js documentation but I can't seem to find anyway to accomplish this. How can this be done?